# Orientation does not rotate in iOS 10 but does rotate in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

I don't have a physical device with iOS 10 to test this on but in any device running iOS 10 in the simulator, the app doesn't rotate, it stays in portrait. However, in iOS 11, it rotates fine. All of the orientation boxes are checked in the Info.plist and whether I use or omit (which is the only bit of code in the entire app that deals with orientations):

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown
}
```

in any view controller (root or otherwise), it has no affect in iOS 10. The app is entirely constraint based and there are navigation controllers, which I've read can cause issues. But everything that has been suggested in those answers didn't work for me. Something is preventing the app from rotating in iOS 10 and I cannot figure it out.

This method also returns nothing in iOS 10 (but works in iOS 11):

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        if size.width > size.height {
            print("orientation: \(UIDevice.current.orientation)")
        } else {
            print("orientation: \(UIDevice.current.orientation)")
        }
    }
```

I've disabled everything in the app and still nothing in iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue which is seen only in iPhone 6 plus simulator. It works fine when we run in device or other simulators iPhone 6, iPhone 7, SE. And also this issue is not seen in iPhone 6 plus device .